# Multivariable Differentials Problems

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am having a lot of trouble with this question:

For $j=1,...,n$, define the function $f_{j}$ on $R^{n}$\ {0} by $f_{j}(x)=x_{j}$/|x|. Show that $\sum_{i=1}^n x_{j}df_{j}$=0.

Comment: Let's see your calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a direct calculation:

For each j, $df_j = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}dx_i$.
By the product rule, $\frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_j} = \frac{1}{|x|}-\frac{x_j^2}{|x|^3}$.  Meanwhile, if i≠j, then $\frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i} = -\frac{x_ix_j}{|x|^3}$.

Thus, $df_j = \frac{dx_j}{|x|}-\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x_ix_j}{|x|^3}dx_i$.

Multiplying by $x_j$ and summing on $j$ gives $\sum_{j=1}^nx_jdx_j = \sum_{j=1}^n\frac{x_j}{|x|}dx_j-\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x_ix_j^2}{|x|^3}dx_i$

$= \sum_{j=1}^n\frac{x_j}{|x|}dx_j-\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{x_ix_j^2}{|x|^3}dx_i = \sum_{j=1}^n\frac{x_j}{|x|}dx_j-\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i}{|x|}dx_i = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $f_i=\frac{x_i}{|x|}$ thus
$$\sum f_i^2=1$$

The differential is therefore

$$\sum 2 f_i df_i =0$$

or 
$$\sum \frac{x_i}{|x|}  df_i =0$$ now multipy by $|x|$ to get 
$$\sum x_i df_i =0$$

A direct calculation should also work but this is more conceptual.

Comment: Thank you but how did you know to differentiate the inside term like that (is there a rule/concept that allows you to do that).